# how to enable docker-compose installation on ec2 - outbound ssh allowed but not working?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-security-group

I did enable sec group- ssh traffic outbound rules from anywhere
after ssh into my ec2 server, i tried to run the script from the docker [website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository):

```
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

this tries to connect to outside of ec2 but fails. what is the reason? how to fix it?

```
0% [Connecting to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (3.87.126.146)]

Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (9
1.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (1
85.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80
(185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:8
0 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:8
0 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used
instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the outbound traffic is set from port 0 to port 0 for a destination 0.0.0.0/0, or simply select type to "All traffic".

If you just set ssh port, can not enable outbound traffic to use curl or download any thing